# Java scribe client with OAuth 2 Resource Owner Password Credentials

Tags: java, android, oauth, oauth-2.0, scribe

I am building a mobile app that uses the Authorization Grant type "Resource Owner Password Credentials"

Tested the code in Ruby with the "oauth2" gem and it works fine

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new('the_client_id', 'the_client_secret', :site => "http://example.com")
access_token = client.password.get_token('user@example.com', 'sekret')
puts access_token.token
```

Java code

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
        .provider(MyApi.class)
        .apiKey("the_client_id")
        .apiSecret("the_client_secret")
        .debug()
        .build();
// the next step should provide ('user@example.com', 'sekret')
// because I am using "Resource Owner Password Credentials"
// http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#page-53
Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
```

How can I provide the username and password in Scribe (or with other library preferably compatible with Android)?

Right now I cannot find a way to do this with Scribe extending "DefaultApi20".

Answer (score 3):

I understand now that this is just a POST request

```
curl -i http://localhost:3000/oauth/token \
  -F grant_type=password \
  -F client_id=the_client_id \
  -F client_secret=the_client_secret \
  -F username=user@example.com \
  -F password=sekret
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do with using Scribe itself?

Comment: @TomLeese I used [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for the client.`public Interface MyService {
      @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/oauth/token")
        Token login(@Field("grant_type") String grant_type,
                    @Field("client_id") String client_id, @Field("client_secret") String client_secret,
                    @Field("username") String email, @Field("password") String pin);
}`

Comment: Did you mean scribe is not needed at all?

Comment: Yes, you can handle everything with HTTP requests or use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)